# Why should an electron orbit decay?

Tags: particle-physics

I have heard physicists say that 'if' an electron was a particle then it's orbit would decay so it would crash into the nucleus.

How do they propose that it would lose it's energy in order to decay?

Comment: Accelerated charges radiate. You would have found this by e.g. reading the [shortcomings section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model#Shortcomings) of the Wikipedia article.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 3):

In classical electrodynamics, charged particles radiate electromagnetic waves when accelerated. An electron in a circular orbit has radial acceleration. Think about where the energy of the electromagnetic waves could possibly come from, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Techincally, in classical electrodynamics charged particles radiate waves, not photons.